# How does the null check operator work in Dart

Tags: dart, null-coalescing

I'm using [this](https://github.com/enlearacademy/todo-Amplify-Auth) repository to familiarize myself with Amazon's Cognito user system. In the file lib/screens/signup_screen.dart, starting at line 27 there is this piece of code:

```
          TextFormField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Email"),
            controller: _emailController,
            validator: (value) =>
                !validateEmail(value) ? "Email is Invalid" : null,
          ),
```

However, since we have null safety in Dart since version 2.x, this piece of code fails with the error message: `The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'`.

What I got from that is that *value* may not be equal to null and the code cannot guarantee that as it is. Please correct me if I'm wrong and I'm also hoping someone can explain to me why the code cannot guarantee null safety here. If the textfield is empty, *value* should be equal to `""` instead of `null`.

Anyhow, I decided to use the ternary operator to fix this issue:

```
!validateEmail(value == null ? "" : value) ? ...
```

Which the IDE suggested I correct to:

```
!validateEmail(value ?? "") ? ...
```

Dart also suggested to insert a null check as another alternative:

```
!validateEmail(value!) ? ....
```

Up till now, I have just been using these fixes as a workaround to produce code fast without trying to understand what's actually going on.

So what's the difference between these methods? Does the `??` in the second method have an integrated `== null` check and is it exactly the same as writing `value == null ? "" : value`?

Also, what does the nullcheck `value!` do? Yes, it checks if *value* is equal to null, but what does it do for me when *value* is in fact equal to null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `??` is a null-aware operator , which returns the expression on its left unless that expression’s value is null, in which case it evaluates and returns the expression on its right:

```dart
print(1 ?? 3); // <-- Prints 1.
print(null ?? 12); // <-- Prints 12.
```

Which is the same as doing a ternary operator but more readable.

The bang operator `!` casts aways the nullability of the variable, meaning YOU explicitly say that the value CAN'T be `null`.

> Of course, like any cast, using ! comes with a loss of static safety.
> The cast must be checked at runtime to preserve soundness and it may
> fail and throw an exception.

For further reading check out the [documentation](https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet).

Comment: Hi and many thanks for your super fast reply. The part about ?? is clear to me now, thanks. But assume I have a variable *value* that IS equal to null. When I write ```value!``` I'm saying it can't be null, but it in fact is. What happens then?

Comment: It will fail with an exception, `null aware operator used on null value`

Answer (score 1):

You can start learning more about sound null safety in Dart here: [Understanding Null Safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

The null assertion `value!` is equal to casting to a non-nullable type: `value as String`. It raises an exception if `value` is null.

The conditional `??` operator acts as you expect: `value ?? ""` is a shorthand equivalent for `value != null ? value : ""`

Answer (score 1):

> What I got from that is that *value* may not be equal to null and the code cannot guarantee that as it is.

`value` *might* be `null`, but `validateEmail` requires that its argument is *not* `null`.

> can explain to me why the code cannot guarantee null safety here. If the *textfield* is empty, value should be equal to `""` instead of `null`.

Because that's what [`TextFormField`'s constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField/TextFormField.html) specifies.  Its `validator` parameter is declared to be a `FormFieldValidator<String>?`, and [`FormFieldValidator<T>`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormFieldValidator.html) is defined to be a `String? Function(T? value)`.  In other words, the `validator` callback is declared to be a function that must accept `null` as an argument.  The compiler does not have semantic knowledge to know whether `TextFormField` will actually invoke that callback with `null` instead of an empty string in practice.

> So what's the difference between these methods? Does the `??` in the second method have an integrated `== null` check and is it exactly the same as writing `value == null ? "" : value`?

`??` is one of Dart's *null-aware* operators; it automatically checks for `null` for you.  [As stated in the Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#conditional-expressions):

> *expr1 ?? expr2*
>
> If *expr1* is non-null, returns its value; otherwise, evaluates and returns the value of *expr2*.

So yes, it is equivalent to `expr1 == null ? expr2 : expr1` (except that `??` would evaluate `expr1` only once, which matters if evaluation has side effects).  You should prefer `??` anyway because it better conveys intent.

> Also, what does the nullcheck `value!` do? Yes, it checks if *value* is equal to null, but what does it do for me when *value* is in fact equal to null?

`value!` will *throw an exception* (specifically a `TypeError`) if `value` turns out to be `null` at runtime.  Do not use `!` unless you can *logically guarantee* that `value` will not be `null`.

Comment: Ah, I see, so using ```value ?? ""``` is the safest option here.